# Using powershell to update certain field in API

Tags: powershell, api, rest

I'm trying to make a script that updates a specific field which is located deep in the API's structure (XML).
I got so far as retrieving the value for that specific node like so:

```
$ProdData = Invoke-Restmethod -Uri $ProdUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing
$ProdAttributes = $ProdData.list | Select-Xml -Xpath "//resource/attributes"
$SelectXML = $ProdAttributes | Select-Xml -XPath "//attribute[@name='required-parameters']"
$SelectItem = $SelectXML | Select-Xml -XPath "//parameters/parameter[@name='modelInputParameters']"
```

The value I want to overwrite is $SelectItem.Node.value with value $NewModelInput, but I'm not really sure how to go about this.

The structure looks a bit like this:

```
<resource>
<attributes>
  <attribute name="required-parameters">
    <parameters>
    <parameter step="persist_imported_data_strings_hidden" name="modelInputParameters" value="{'info':'3','horlgto':'0','horlgtb':'700'}" committed="false"/>
            </parameters>
        </attribute>
</attributes>  
</resource>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `$SelectItem = $SelectXML | Select-Xml`, I would suggest using `SelectSingleNode()`.

Something like this:

```
# the new value for the `value attribute`
$NewModelInput = "{'info':'999','horlgto':'888','horlgtb':'777'}"

$SelectItem = $SelectXML.SelectSingleNode("//parameters/parameter[@name='modelInputParameters']")
# update the value attribute for this node
$SelectItem.SetAttribute("value", $NewModelInput)
```

Comment: This works easier, thanks, however I would still need to "Put" it into the API in some way.

Comment: @T.Huisman That wasn't the question I think as there is no way for anyone but you to check what the API expects when you do `Invoke-Restmethod -Uri $ProdUrl -Method Put`..  I answered _"The value I want to overwrite is $SelectItem.Node.value with value $NewModelInput, but I'm not really sure how to go about this."_

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, I want to update the field on the server side. My hope was that I could do it in a simple way like how I got the information.

Comment: @T.Huisman Well, you need to 'Get' the data first like you do, then change the attribute like I showed you and next 'Put' or 'Post' the updated xml ($ProdData) back to the server. Since I don't know anything obout that server's API, you'll have to try yourself.

Comment: I was able to post the whole xml with changed value, thanks!